# Custom List-Like Environment

Tags: tables, environments, enumerate

I would like to create a custom 'axiom' environment to mimic the following:

[image]

I have some requirements: I would it to take a letter as an option so I could replace the 'P' in the above screenshot with any letter. I would also like the width of the environment to fill the remaining horizontal space. Finally, I want to automatically add the first row with a counter I was able to create this next screenshot using the code below:
[image]

```
\begin{definition}
    A \emph{poset} is a set in which a binary relation $x \le y $ is defined, which
satisfies for all $x, y, z $ the following conditions:\\

\begin{tabular}{  m{1em}  m{.5\textwidth} m{1cm}  } 
  P1. & For all $x$, $x \le x$. & (Reflexivity) \\ 
  P2. & If $x \le y$ and $y \le x$, then $x = y$ & (Antisymmetry) \\ 
  P3. & If $x \le y$ and $y \le z$, then $x \le z$ & (Transitivity)\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{definition}
```

Naturally, this was done manually with no counters. The alignment of the text is off and it does not fill the available space. I would to automate it as much as possible. I must admit I am extremely new when it comes to using table in LaTeX. Any help will be must appreciated.

Comment: Instead of posting code fragments, it's helpful if you embed your fragments into a small compilable document that people can play with. Why not just use a regular enumeration using the `enumitem` package? e.g. `\begin{enumerate}[label=P\arabic*.]` You can use `\hfill` to move the parenthesized stuff to the right margin.

Comment: The problem with the `\hfill` is that the first parentheses will not be aligned.

Comment: @projetmbc They are not aligned in the example the OP is trying to mimic, so `\hfill` is appropriate.

Comment: Sorry. You are totally right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the table formatting you want with `tabularx`, using the `X` column specification for the middle column to fill the maximum available space, and `r` for the right-aligned column.

Define an empty command for the label and a counter for the number. Then create an environment (`axiomata`) for the axiom lists that takes an optional argument for the label. Zero out the counter and set the label to the optional argument if it is there. Then set up your `tabularx`.

Within that environment the `axiom` command takes two arguments, and from those it makes a table row of three cells: first the label and number (incrementing the counter), then your first and second arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcounter{axiomNum}
\NewDocumentCommand{\axiomMark}{}{}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{axiomata}{ o }
{%
    \par\vspace{1ex}%
    \IfValueTF{#1} {\RenewDocumentCommand{\axiomMark}{}{#1}} {}%
    \setcounter{axiomNum}{0}%
    \noindent\tabularx{\textwidth}{l X r}
}
{%
    \endtabularx
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\axiom}{ m m }{%
    \stepcounter{axiomNum}
    \axiomMark\theaxiomNum. & #1 & #2\tabularnewline
}

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
    A \emph{poset} is a set in which a binary relation $x \le y $ is
    defined, which
    satisfies for all $x, y, z $ the following conditions:

    \begin{axiomata}[P]
        \axiom{For all $x$, $x \le x$.} {(Reflexivity)}
        \axiom{If $x \le y$ and $y \le x$, then $x = y$.} {(Antisymmetry)}
        \axiom{If $x \le y$ and $y \le z$, then $x \le z$.} {(Transitivity)}
    \end{axiomata}

\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) with an `\hfill` to push the content to the right. However, this doesn't allow the list to break across the page boundary. You can also define your own list-like environment (say, `propertylist`) using [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,tabularx}

\newlist{propertylist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[propertylist]{%
  label={\propertylistprefix\arabic*.},
  ref={\propertylistprefix\arabic*},
  nosep,
  labelindent=0pt,
  labelsep=0pt,
  align=left,
  leftmargin=!}
\newcommand{\propertylistprefix}{P}% Default prefix

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l @{~} X @{}} 
  P1. & For all $x$, $x \leq x$.                      \hfill  (Reflexivity) \\ 
  P2. & If $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$, then $x = y$    \hfill (Antisymmetry) \\ 
  P3. & If $x \leq y$ and $y \leq z$, then $x \leq z$ \hfill (Transitivity) 
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\begin{propertylist}
  \item For all $x$, $x \leq x$.                      \hfill  (Reflexivity)
  \item If $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$, then $x = y$    \hfill (Antisymmetry)
  \item If $x \leq y$ and $y \leq z$, then $x \leq z$ \hfill (Transitivity) 
\end{propertylist}

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\propertylistprefix}{L}% Change prefix
\begin{propertylist}
  \item For all $x$, $x \leq x$.                      \hfill  (Reflexivity)
  \item If $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$, then $x = y$    \hfill (Antisymmetry)
  \item If $x \leq y$ and $y \leq z$, then $x \leq z$ \hfill (Transitivity) 
\end{propertylist}

\end{document}
```